# Particle js background for angular project?

Tags: angularjs, particles.js

Can anyone explain how to add particle js background for angular 6 project?
I followed some tutorials as bellow link.but it didn't work for me.
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer below or tell me if you are having problems  implementing it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I got it to work in my NG6 project:

1. Install particles.js from npm:  **npm i particles.js --save** or make sure is already installed.
2. Add **node_modules/particles.js/particles.js** in your scripts section in angular.json
3. In your component add: **declare var particlesJS: any;** before @component
4. Go to [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) and modify the particles to your liking then download the particlesjs-config.json file
5. Store that file in your assets/data folder as particles.json
6. In your component html template add a div with id = "particles-js"
7. In your component ngOnInit add the following code:

   particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/particles.json', function() {
               console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
             });

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Added code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ParticlesConfig } from './../../../../../assets/data/particles';

declare var particlesJS: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heading',
  templateUrl: './heading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heading.component.scss']
})
export class HeadingComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/
        particlesJS('particles-js', ParticlesConfig, function() {
            console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
          });
    }
}
```

the template

```
<div class="h-75 bg header">
    <div  id="particles-js" class="w-100 header-particles"  >

    </div>
    <div class="header-container w-100">
        <div>
            <h1> Big Header</h1>
            <div>small header</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the use in another component

```
<app-heading></app-heading>
<main>
  <app-features></app-features>
  <app-pricing-tier></app-pricing-tier>
  <app-testimonials></app-testimonials>
  <app-trusted-by></app-trusted-by>
</main>
```

Comment: Did exactly this and recieving error "Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null
    at window.particlesJS" Know of a fix?

Comment: Just had to setup the same thing in Angular 7. Had to initialize it in AfterViewInit rather than OnInit to avoid the getElementsByClassName errors.

Comment: @codephobia Weird. I am using angular 7.2.3 in a new project and had no issues putting it in the ngOnInit

Comment: @codephobia. Are you by chance creating the component in an ngFor or other construct that could delay the creation of the element?

Comment: @AlbertoL.Bonfiglio Can you tell me, how to properly include this into my test? The basic `should create` test are not working, due to `ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined`. I am testing in Karama and also tried to include the declaration of the `particlesJS` variable by outsourcing it into `typings.d.ts` and including it as `files:['typing.d.ts']` in my `karma.conf.ts`(Works fine on serving, but not testing)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/matteobruni/ng-particles

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add something more to [Alberto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52461825/5260872)'s answer. I'm on Angular CLI version 8.3.2 and everything works fine. As the question asked, I actually wanted to add it to a background of my component. I achieved that using CSS like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="particles-js">
  </div>
  <div id="over">
      <!--Existing markup-->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#particles-js,
#over {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#over {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

This setup will apply particles.js background under your existing markup.

***EDIT:***

If you are using a Azure App Service on Windows (IIS) to deploy it to production, you might get a 404 not found error for `particles.json`. In that case create a `web.config` file as follows in `src` folder, and include it in `assets` array in `angular.json`

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**angular.json**

```
"assets": [
     "projects/dashboard/src/favicon.ico",
     "projects/dashboard/src/assets",
     "projects/dashboard/src/web.config"
]
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/matteobruni/ng-particles

Comment: Wow, Thanks. I was not aware of this. @Caelan

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement particle animation using "angular-particle" which is an implementation of particle.js with TypeScript for Angular

It's implementation is pretty straight forward and you can find it in link below
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-particle

**Edited**:

Here is the running example of angular-particle in angular 8
https://github.com/SunnyMakode/angular-particle-demo

Once you pull the code from github,

1. type "npm install --save" and hit enter from terminal window
2. type "ng serve" and hit enter

Comment: "angular-particle"  is working fine for me. I am using Angular 8 by the way.
I will post the github link shortly for reference

Comment: Hi Timothy,

Here is the running example of angular-particle in angular 8
https://github.com/SunnyMakode/angular-particle-demo

Once you pull the code from github,

>> type "npm install --save" and hit enter from terminal window

>> type "ng serve" and hit enter

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/matteobruni/ng-particles